# C - How would I extract Even numbers from an array and place them into another array called EvenNumbers?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm tasked with writing a function that will identify all the even numbers in an sample array {10,2,9,3,1,98,8] and place them in an array called EvenNumbers. I have to allow the function so that it works with different combinations of numbers in the array not just the numbers in the sample array above.

I'm wondering is there any way to add numbers to an array that could be different every time? How would I extract the even numbers an place them into an array? Also
for the even array size its giving me an error that the expression must have a constant value but when I use const int it still gives me that error.

Here is the full question.

"Using the array of sample values {10,2,9,3,1,98,8}, write a function that will identify all the even numbers in an array and place it in an array called EvenNumbers. The function must work in all cases, not just in the case of the array shown. Assume that the array size is always available through a global constant called MAX"

Here is what I have so far. I've no idea how I will extract the even numbers from a for loop and place them in an array. I also dont know what the "expression must have a constant value" is about?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void EvenNumber(int Array[], int size);

int main()
{
int array[7] = { 10,2,9,3,1,98,8 };

EvenNumber(array, 7);
}

void EvenNumber(int Array[], int size)
{
int i;
int EvenArraySize;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{

    if (Array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        EvenArraySize++;

    }

}

int Even[EvenArraySize];

}
```

Comment: You should use malloc() to create an array with dynamic size. The EvenArraySize is not a constant value, Another option is to set Even size to Max.

Comment: @m.r226: That is standard C. VLAs are part of every C99 and any modern C11 compiler! No need for a constant length (which does not mean it is a _good_ idea)..

Comment: If the quote is all of your asignment, then you are not required to remove the even numbers from the input array. I can also not see anything which requires you to make the EvenArray sized so that it **only** contains the even numbers found. Therefor I recommed to a) treat input array as read-only b) creat the EvenArray of same size as inpput array (i.e. MAX) c) verify with your instructor that this is OK. d) just test each number in input array for odd/even and if even copy to EvenArray. Since this is a homework question I will, as StackOverflow recommends, not give the code.

Comment: We used to use obstack.h part of gcc for that. Might be outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to go is to use `malloc` to allocate just the right amount of memory.

1. Count the number of even numbers
2. Allocate the space needed to store them
3. Copy even numbers in this space
4. Do whatever you want with these numbers
5. Free the allocated space

Snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 7

int
main()
{
  int array[] = {10,2,9,3,1,98,8};
  int *even_numbers;
  int i, nb_even_numbers;

  for (i = 0, nb_even_numbers = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        nb_even_numbers++;
    }
  even_numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * nb_even_numbers);
  if (!even_numbers)
    {
      perror("malloc");
      return 1;
    }
  for (i = 0, nb_even_numbers = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        even_numbers[nb_even_numbers++] = array[i];
    }
  /* do your stuff here */
  free(even_numbers);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can never return a statically declared array from a function (even though you don't explicitly try, your `Even` array is destroyed when `EvenNumber` returns) Why? The function stack frame for `EvenNumber` is released for reuse on return and any locally declared arrays are no longer valid.

You either need to pass a second array as a parameter to `EvenNumber`, or you can dynamically allocate storage for `Even` in `EvenNumber` (with, e.g. `malloc` or `calloc` or `realloc`) and return a pointer to the beginning of the array. (you must also have some way to return the size or use a constant for a max size).

There is no need to use `%` (`modulo`) to test whether a number is odd/even. All you need to do is look at `bit-0` (little endian). If it is `0`, then the number is *odd*, if it is `1`, then its *even*. Much more efficient than calling modulo which incorporates division.

Finally, `main` is type `int` and therefore returns a value.

Putting those pieces together, you can do something simple like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void EvenNumber (int *array, int *even, int size, int *esize);

int main (void)
{
    int array[] = { 10,2,9,3,1,98,8 }, 
        i, n = sizeof array / sizeof *array,
        even[n],       /* a VLA of the same size as array is fine here */
        esize = 0;

    EvenNumber (array, even, n, &esize);

    printf ("array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %2d", array[i]);

    printf ("\neven : ");
    for (i = 0; i < esize; i++)
        printf (" %2d", even[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

void EvenNumber (int *array, int *even, int size, int *esize)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if ((array[i] & 1) == 0)    /* simply looking at bit-0 is all you need */
            even[(*esize)++] = array[i];
}
```

**Note:** `esize` is passed as a pointer to `EvenNumber` and updated within the function so that the number of elements in `even` are available back in the calling function (`main()` here).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayeven
array:  10  2  9  3  1 98  8
even :  10  2 98  8
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.